# Можно ли как то сделать сортировку списка по одному элементу в большую сторону, а по другому в меньшую

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list

Можно ли как то сделать сортировку списка по одному элементу в большую сторону, а по другому в меньшую?

`a = [('Jhon', '00:25', 5), ('Alex', '00:21', 3)]`

Например по a[1] элементу в большую а по a[2] большую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [('Jhon', '00:25', 5), ('Alex', '00:21', 3)]
b = sorted(a, key = lambda x: (x[0], -x[2]))
```